# TGestureManager Swipe Left and Right

Tags: android, ios, delphi, swipe

So I've got a tab control with several items (labels, etc) on it.

If I have something like the following it doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't seem to - correctly.  If I "Swipe Left", and the gesture runs across a series of descendants, will it work?

```
procedure TFormMain.TabControlAppGesture(Sender: TObject; const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
   if (EventInfo.GestureID = sgiLeft) then
      begin
        //go right and show report
        TabControlApp.ActiveTab:=TabItemReport;
      end
   else if (EventInfo.GestureID = sgiRight) then
      begin
        //Go Left and show data
        TabControlApp.ActiveTab:=TabItemData;
      end
   else
      begin
        //Who knows what they did and who cares
      end;

  //handle event regardless
  Handled:=True;
end;
```

I guess the real question is: Can I have a global app swipe that can be detected no matter what the user swipes on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't show "something like" your code. Instead, copy and paste *actual* code that reproduces the behavior you've observed. Also describe the behavior you observe, and the behavior you expected to see instead. And instead of asking whether your code works, why don't you test it and find out for yourself?

Comment: That is actual code - and it doesn't work reliably.  Doesn't matter if sensitivity is turned up from 80 to 100.  It's very flaky - not sure if that's Delphi's problem or the way it's coded.